# Best Practices for AppleScript Records

Tags: workflows, mac

Not sure this is quite the right question for here, but here goes. Apologies if I'm wrong on that.

**Summary //** In general, is a Plist the best way to store and recall data that will be frequently amended or is it better to store that data in a CSV, Excel, or something else?

**Context //** 
After much hacking, I have created an AppleScript app that tracks a loop of user responses and then builds folders accordingly. *(We use AS because the script interacts with CaptureOne which is still pushing forward with AS.)* Inputs are gathered every few minutes. The next step is to record the values and lists generated so that a) they may be recalled even if the script terminates and b) output them to text for record keeping by others. Further goals include reconciling files and folders and sharing reports to Google Suite for team visibility.

Again, is a Plist the best way to store and recall data that will be frequently amended or is it better to store that data as a text file, or CSV, some other method?

Comment: Asking for "the best way" is not a good fit for this board. Among other things, you haven't told us the frequency, volume or other measures, nor the reliability and endurance of your application.

Comment: @BobDalgleish, thanks for the feedback. I can provide more details, but sounds like I should just take this down. Where do you suggest is a better place to post a question like this?